# Confusion About Date Conversion in R

Tags: r

I know this has been asked here, but i did according to several answers but still received NA value, or value changed my year 2016 into 2020.

I need to convert factor into date. I tried as.Date function

```
Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date <- as.Date(Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date,"%d%m%y")
```

also tried:

```
 Reporting_Raw_Data$Submit_Date <- as.Date(Reporting_Raw_Data$Submit_Date,format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

also:

```
Reporting_Raw_Data$Approve_Date <- as.Date(Reporting_Raw_Data$Approve_Date, format="%d-%m-%y")
```

I also tried POSIXct:

```
Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date,
                                             "%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S",tz="")),
                         format = "%Y-%M-%D")
```

also tried ymd_hms

```
Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date <- ymd_hms(Reporting_Raw_Data$Click_Date)
```

None gave me correct conversion.

sample table looks like below:

```
Click_Date

8/16/2016
8/7/2016
```

Comment: Please show some input data.

Comment: You are using the wrong `format`. Why did you use `-` for the separator when the data has `/`?

Comment: @RichScriven which format is the wrong one? the raw data?

Comment: The `format` argument you provide to `as.Date`.  Your data have format month/day/year with century, and you ask for month-day-year with century.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x, format="%m/%d/%Y")` works fine

Comment: @RichScriven I also tried month-day-year without century but it didn't return any results

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks! it works for me!

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share your data. It makes it easier to reproduce and keeps metadata such as class type.

Comment: Lol.  Yeah, exactly what I said to do worked.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi sorry i am new here and i try to figure it out how to close the question and accept the answer.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I have added my own answer... How to see if this question is closed or not...should add one more question like "how to use stack exchange" lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
as.POSIXct(x, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

This is a data format knowledge issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work:

```
Click_Date <- factor(c("8/16/2016",
                   "8/7/2016"))
strptime(as.character(Click_Date), "%m/%e/%Y")
```

Comment: I tried and I got the error message: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Mismatched parens and `as.Date.factor` does this internally

Comment: Any chance you can provide the factor data example?

Comment: Check the modified code...

Comment: `as.character` is still not necessary

Comment: @Rich Scriven you are right as.character is not necessary. I solved a similar problem once with as.character on a factor so I guess it is a habit.